# How to update UISlider from another singleton class?

Tags: ios, uislider

I want to update an `UISlider` according to a `notification` generated by another singleton class.

```
sondDuration=audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration;
songDurationinSeconds=CMTimeGetSeconds(sondDuration);
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This is my notofication generation.

According to this how I can update my `UISlider` in another `ViewController` Please help me.

Comment: can you explain more? We do not know your code so your code snippet does not provide much information for us.

Comment: I want to update my `UISlider` according to the `AVPlayer`. My `AVPlayer` initialized in another `NSObject` class. Then I want to update my `UIViewController's slider` according to the values return by the AVPlayer

Comment: @Pfitz AVPlayer is initialized by clicking a play btn in the same viewcontroller, After clicking that play btn in viewcontroller It calls to the NSObject class's init method and initialize the play btn and start to play songs. While playing those songe NSObject class should return AVPlayer values back to the same ViewController to update the UISlider

Answer (score 2):

You can use Delegate Method For that

Like the given Below:

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add a NSNotification in your viewcontroller which updates the UISlider

In your viewcontroller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveSliderUpdate:) 
    name:@"UpdateSlider"
    object:nil];

- (void) receiveSliderUpdate:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"UpdateSlider"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"UpdateSlider"])
        // do something with your slider
}
```

In your controller add the code to notify your view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"UpdateSlider" 
        object:self];
```

Comment: then how can I pas the value into the viewcontroller using this UpdateSlider notification. I want to pass AVPlayer values into the viewvontroller inorder to update a slider

Comment: inside receiveSliderUpdate method what I want to do is assign those received values into the slider value

Comment: put the values in the userinfo dictionary! The above mentioned message has a version where you can send an NSDictionary with the notification!